# How to parse javascript for links with java?

Tags: java, javascript, html, parsing

I'm writing a program (in Java) that needs to extract links from webpages. I'm using htmlParser (http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) but I'm only able to extract html links (defined with `<a href="...">`) and I don't know how to handle javascript code to extract links from... can you help me??

Comment: There are some missing parts in your question. Is it formatting issue?

Comment: Please edit your question : it's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: I can't understand why it's hard to understand what I mean, is it because of my poor english? Please tell me more.

Comment: @Raffo did my answer helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rhino with [DOM environment, written in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/).
By the way it is written by John Resig.

Comment: I've never played with DOM, but I'll take a look at your link, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Parser from sourceforge is useful. I have used it to parse a whole bunch of HTML already. However, parsing JS is different. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is probally the most comprehensive tool out there. [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) . Everything you want to do can be done with Rhino.